# Activity indicator is blocked by button

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I added an activity indicator on my button, and animate it when button is tapped, however, it is animating every time, but it can't be seen, here's my code:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        self.openCircle(withCenter: sender.center, dataSource: self.calculator!.iterateWPItems()){}
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

Comment: hide this `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()` and check once

Comment: try to do in main queue , you are fetching something from on same button action

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik no it still doesn't show

Comment: @Vinodh can you demonstrate it?

Comment: @BrightFuture, is `openCircle` method an asynchronous method? If it is then the answers should work. Otherwise, there may be some problem in `activityIndicator` implementation

Comment: @BrightFuture did you set `hidesWhenStopped` of your `UIActivityIndicatorView` to `true` and the initial state of the `UIActivityIndicatorView` to not animating?

Comment: @d.felber yes, I did

Comment: @BrightFuture did you add breakpoints at `self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()` and `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()`? Is `activityIndicator` non-nil in both cases? From your example code I would expect the `UIActivityIndicatorView` not even to start animating...

Comment: @d.felber it prints out true in isAnimating method

Comment: @BrightFuture yeah sure. Directly after you start the animation. But directly afterwards the animation is stopped. `openCircle` is unrelated - unless you do something with `activityIndicator` in it.

Comment: @d.felber I checked, it's not nil in both cases

Comment: @BrightFuture Currently there is to few information to help you with your problem. Please add the `openCircle` implementation and how/where you add `activityIndicator` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just write this in `completion handler`.No need to use `dispatch_after`

```
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    print(activityIndicator.isAnimating)

    openCircle(withCenter: sender.center, dataSource: calculator!.iterateWPItems()){

// place webservice data processing here
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
        }
    }
```

**Swift 3:**

```
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    print(activityIndicator.isAnimating)

    openCircle(withCenter: sender.center, dataSource: calculator!.iterateWPItems()){
// place webservice data processing here

        DispatchQueue.main.async { 
          self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

        }
    }
```

Comment: after async call place the code. You will get data in async call . may be async call executed very fast that's why you are not able to see animation . Add some delay to check animation . above is a sample only .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, your `openCircle` method is an asynchronous method. I think you are supposed to stop your activity indicator when you receive call back from your method. Please try this modified code.

```
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
print(activityIndicator.isAnimating)

openCircle(withCenter: sender.center, dataSource: calculator!.iterateWPItems()){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
    }
}
```

For Swift 3,

```
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
print(activityIndicator.isAnimating)

openCircle(withCenter: sender.center, dataSource: calculator!.iterateWPItems()){
    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Using NSOperation,

```
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
print(activityIndicator.isAnimating)

openCircle(withCenter: sender.center, dataSource: calculator!.iterateWPItems()){
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
       self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. You are supposed to make `openCircle` an asynchronous method. It's pretty simple. You need to insert your code inside `dispatch_async`